# wkhtmltopdf html table side line

Tags: c#, html, html-table, wkhtmltopdf

I use wkhtmltopdf with footer.html , header.html and use border in main html code. But when I use border table side lines be longer than table. How can I fix it ?
[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfSir.jpg)

main.html

```html
<style type="text/css">
    span {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

  tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    table {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 9px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>İL <br />İLÇE</th>
            <th>BİNA ADI</th>
            <th>AÇIKLAMA</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@(item != null && item.IL != null ? item.IL : "")<br /> @(item != null && item.ILCE != null ? item.ILCE : "")</td>
                <td>@(item != null && item.BINA_ADI != null ? item.BINA_ADI : "")</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7"><b>TOPLAM :</b></td>
            <td colspan="5"><b>@toplam</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

header.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
   <style type='text/css'>
            
table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
 
    </style>
</head>
<body style=" margin:0;padding-top:20px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: 8pt;text-align: justify;">
 
</table>
<table style='width: 100%; text-align: justify; margin-top:80px;'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
</body>
</html>
```

footer.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
    <script>
        function subst() {
            var vars={};
            var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
            for (var i in x)
            {
                var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
            }
            var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
            for (var i in x)
            {
                var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
                for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding-top:50px;" onload="subst()">

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr> 
            <td style="text-align:center;width:20%;">
                <span class="page"></span> / <span class="topage"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Guillaume thanks for explane. I edited question.